# ExoPlayer in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, exoplayer2.x, android-viewmodel

I am trying to use exoplayer in my app, and i am following MVVM design pattern, i want to make PlayerViewModel class where it handle all the actions of player (play tracks,pause,next,... so on), but i faced a problem that i need to initialize the SimpleExoPlayer with **context** but ViewModel could not have **context**

```
SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getApplicationContext(), trackSelector);
```

any suggestion what i should do ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AndroidViewModel. It contains the application context. It is in the Android Architecture Components library.